# How to remove white space at the top of page

Tags: html, css

I need help finding the element I need to adjust to remove the white space at the top of [this](https://shiftins.com/) page

I think I need to do something like this:

```css
margin-top: -30px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change `height` from `60px` to `90px` in your `.site-header`

**UPDATE**

> Ah I see what you did. No I don't want to increase the height of the
>   .site-header. I would either want to apply a (-) margin or increase
>   the height of the image below the header

So, apply `top:-30px` to your `#top-wrap`

**UPDATE 2**

remove the previous `top:-30px` from your `#top-wrap` and change your `margin-top` from your `.site-container` to `60px` ( equal to `header`'s `height`)

Comment: Cleared cache. Did not work:

.site-header {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 999;
 background: #0074E5;
 background: #0c5798;
 height: 90px;
 top:0;
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

Comment: @dippas - you're exactly right.  But the OP should have been able to figure this out himself, using a tool like Firebug or Chrome.

Comment: Ah I see what you did. No I don't want to increase the height of the .site-header. I would either want to apply a (-) margin or increase the height of the image below the header.

Comment: @paulsm4 relax man I'm not a professional coder just a website owner trying to diy my site.

Comment: @dippas thank you! But it looks like it's the image size causing the gap not a margin. I tried increasing #top-wrap { from 420px to 450px but that was not correct. I moved the image so you can see. this is the item I need to identify. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't say margin in my answer, I said apply `top:-30px` only just like that, it is very different

Comment: Sorry I said that because I thought that was also the object for the image size. I did your suggestion and it moved the gap to the bottom by the black bar. I left it live for you to see.

Comment: then the easiest way is go with my first solution

Comment: @dippas please help me identify the .object that controls the main banner image.

Comment: I think #top-wrap is the primary container I want to know the image object inside it? I hope that's the correct way to say it...

Comment: Then increase its height so that it reaches the bottom of the navigation.

Comment: `top-wrap` is the container and HAS the image as `background-image` therefore it controls everything

Comment: When I increase the min-height and max-height of #top-wrap it adjusts the container size but does not change the image size. Also, background-image only appears in .sidebar { and .footer-widgets-4 a.social-icon {

Comment: because image is too small

Comment: Don't hate me for this but I'm using .site-container { margin-top: 95px; to push down the page so the breadcrumbs don't clip on my /blog/* pages.

https://www.shiftins.com/blog/the-ins-and-outs-of-rv-insurance/

Comment: If I could just increase the height of the actual image inside .site-container or define it, if it's not, I would be styled appropriately to the way I styled the rest of the css. Seriously, thanks for your help man.

Comment: you could do what I just told you, and then increase `padding` in your `site-inner` from 40px to 75px (95px - 60px = 35), You would solve both white space and breadcrumbs